# Dumb qestion: how get json to read html?

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

I'm very new to Json and JQuery. I got autocomplete Jquery UI plugin that return a Json Object. Ex it return `["Tim ferriss","stack overflow","<strong>Oscar</strong> Wilde"]`
In the browser the strong tag is seen as `&lt;strong&gt;Osca&lt;/strong&gt;r Wilde`

Why? I think is a very stupid error..

**Edit:** Nothing worked so far.This is the code

```
function highlight(s, t) {
var matcher = new RegExp("("+$.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(t)+")", "ig" );
return s.replace(matcher, "<strong>$1</strong>");
}
```

I think that json object is converted in a javascript object. I have the same issue anyway

Answer (score 4):

You would do well to figure out why the HTML is being escaped. There should be some good reason (often security related).

Have a look here
http://erlend.oftedal.no/blog/?blogid=14

Answer (score 3):

The items in the JSON object are text values only, they are not pure HTML items, so you cannot style them this way.

Have a look here: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete

You can style it with the jQuery UI themes.

Answer (score 0):

make your query as html, by default it is assumed json. So string sent by the server translates safe values by getter.

In [jquery post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) page there is an example like:

```
 $.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" },
  function(data){
    process(data);
  }, "xml");
```

you can try replacing html with xml